# How to configure catch-all in Exchange2010 hub-transport environment?

Tags: exchange-server-2010, catch-all

This link is explaining how to do it in an edge transport environment, indicating that it is not relevant for hub-transport. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(EXCHG.80).aspx

do you know what is the way to get it done in hub-transport environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [CatchAllAgent](http://catchallagent.codeplex.com) on CodePlex. This was written to work with Exchange 2007 but it does work with 2010 as well.

The key trick is to install it in the TransportRoles directory as per these links:

http://catchallagent.codeplex.com/discussions/218519?ProjectName=catchallagent

http://catchallagent.codeplex.com/discussions/62204?ProjectName=catchallagent

1) download the ZIP

2) unzip to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\agents\catchall"`
 [or wherever the TransportRoles\agents path is]

3) Edit the config.xml file in this directory to define the domains to be handled

4) Run Exchange Management Shell end execute these commands:

```
install-transportagent -Name "CatchAll Agent" -TransportAgentFactory:CatchAll.CatchAllFactory -AssemblyPath:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\agents\catchall\CatchAllAgent.dll"

get-transportagent

enable-transportagent "CatchAll Agent"

net stop MSExchangeTransport

net start MSExchangeTransport
```

5) Send some test mails to see if it works!